# JPA: How to filter an association?

Tags: jpa, jpa-2.0, criteria-api

My model:

```
@Entity
class Person {
    @Id
    long id;
    @OneToMany
    Set<Employment> employments =  new HashSet<Employment>();
}

@Entity
class Employment {
    @Id
    long id;
    @ManyToOne
    Company company;
    Date from;
    Date until;
}
```

It's an association between a `Person` and a `Company` that's restricted by a time interval.

I'm looking for a JPA criteria query to select all `Person`s and their employments at a given time.

The expected result is a `List<Person>` containing *all* people, where the collection `employments` of each `Person` contains only employments that match certain criteria (or no emplyments at all).

`@Where` is not a sensible approach because the filter criteria for employments is variable, e.g. I would want to select all employments of a person at any given time.

Is this even a reasonable thing to do? Any suggestions how to do this differently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not a reasonable thing to do. An entity is supposed to represent the data that is in the database, and not the date returned by a particular query.

I would simply add a ManyToOne association from `Employment` to `Person`, and search for employments. If you need the set of persons, just iterate through the employments and add each employment's person to a Set. If you want the persons associated with their employments at this date, you could use a custom class, or a `MultiMap<Person, Employment>`.

```
String hql = "select employment from Employment employment"
             + " left join fetch employment.person"
             + " where :date between employment.startDate and employment.endDate";
List<Employment> employments = session.createQuery(hql)
                                      .setDate("date", date)
                                      .list();
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint! Searching for the relation instead of the main entity is a nice idea.