# JPA Left Join is producing SQL that returns far too many rows

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa

I need one row per `skill` regardless of whether a `skill` is associated with the `user`. There are < 1000 rows in `skill`. However, the SQL generated by JPA/Hibernate is returning `skill` rows for *all* users.

**JPA**

`select case when su = :user then 1 else 0 end from Skill s left join s.skillUsers su on su = :user order by s.id`

**SQL I wrote that works**

`select case when us.user_id = 1 then 1 else 0 end from skill as s left join user_skills as us on us.skill_id = s.id and us.user_id = 1`

**SQL produced by Hibernate/JPA that does not work**

`select case when user2_.id=? then 1 else 0 end as col_0_0_ from skill skill0_ left outer join user_skills skillusers1_ on skill0_.id=skillusers1_.skill_id left outer join user user2_ on skillusers1_.user_id=user2_.id and (user2_.id=?) order by skill0_.id`

**Skill entity**

```
@BatchSize(size = 100)
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "userSkills")
@LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.EXTRA)
public Set<User> getSkillUsers() {
    return skillUsers;
}
```

**User entity**

```
@JoinTable(name = "user_skills", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id"), uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(name = "UK_user_skill", columnNames = {"user_id", "skill_id"}), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "skill_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
@ManyToMany
@LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.EXTRA)
public Set<Skill> getUserSkills() {
    return userSkills;
}
```

Comment: The SQL's problem is that you need the user2_.id=? to be on the 1st left join involving user_skills.  The reason you get so many records is because it's showing all the skills, all the user skills and then only those users whose ID matches the parameter entered.  I don't know enough about JPA to say how to do this; thus a comment.  But you're problem is there.

Comment: Maybe you need to search the association instead of the entities: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12563445/jpa-how-to-filter-an-association  or maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17154676/criteria-jpa-2-with-3-tables?